# I have a problem trying to use TIM17 on a STM32L432kc

Tags: timer, stm32

As a homework I need to use TIM17 instead of TIM16 to make the integrated LED in the L432kc blink, the LED is in the pin PB3, but it doesn't work.

The program works well with TIM16 but when I change to TIM17 the LED doesn't blink, at first I thought I was forgetting to change a register or something, so I tried with TIM15 and it worked, so I don't know what else can be, can somebody help me?

This is the main code:

```
#include "stm32l432kc_sfr.h"

#define DEBUG(X) Serial.printf("%s\t%x\n",#X,X)

#define TIM_SR_UIF (1<<0)

void my_delay(uint32_t time_ms){
  TIM17_SR &= ~TIM_SR_UIF;
  for (uint32_t i=0; i<=time_ms;i++){
    TIM17_CNT=0;
    while((TIM17_SR & TIM_SR_UIF)==0);
    TIM17_SR &= ~TIM_SR_UIF;
  }
}

void setup() {
  RCC_AHB2ENR |=1<<1;
  GPIOB_MODER &= ~(3<<6);
  GPIOB_MODER |=1<<6;

  RCC_APB2ENR |=1<<18; //Register bit 16, 17 or 18
  TIM17_PSC = 79;
  TIM17_ARR = 999;
  TIM17_CR1 |=1;  //set to 1 
}

void loop(){
  GPIOB_BSRR = 1<<3;
  my_delay(500);
  GPIOB_BSRR = 1<<19;
  my_delay(500);
}
```

And this is the code in stm32l432kc_sfr.h:

```
#define RCC_BASE  0x4002'1000UL
#define RCC_AHB2ENR (*(volatile uint32_t*) (RCC_BASE+0x4c))
#define RCC_APB2ENR (*(volatile uint32_t*) (RCC_BASE+0x60))

#define GPIOB_BASE  0x4800'0400UL
#define GPIOB_MODER (*(volatile uint32_t*) (GPIOB_BASE+0x00))
#define GPIOB_BSRR (*(volatile uint32_t*) (GPIOB_BASE+0x18))

#define TIM16_BASE  0x4001'4400UL 
#define TIM16_CR1 (*(volatile uint32_t*) (TIM16_BASE+0x00))
#define TIM16_SR (*(volatile uint32_t*) (TIM16_BASE+0x10))
#define TIM16_CNT (*(volatile uint32_t*) (TIM16_BASE+0x24))
#define TIM16_PSC (*(volatile uint32_t*) (TIM16_BASE+0x28))
#define TIM16_ARR (*(volatile uint32_t*) (TIM16_BASE+0x2c))

#define TIM17_BASE  0x4001'4800UL
#define TIM17_CR1 (*(volatile uint32_t*) (TIM17_BASE+0x00))
#define TIM17_SR (*(volatile uint32_t*) (TIM17_BASE+0x10))
#define TIM17_CNT (*(volatile uint32_t*) (TIM17_BASE+0x24))
#define TIM17_PSC (*(volatile uint32_t*) (TIM17_BASE+0x28))
#define TIM17_ARR (*(volatile uint32_t*) (TIM17_BASE+0x2C))

#define TIM15_BASE  0x4001'4000UL 
#define TIM15_CR1 (*(volatile uint32_t*) (TIM15_BASE+0x00))
#define TIM15_SR (*(volatile uint32_t*) (TIM15_BASE+0x10))
#define TIM15_CNT (*(volatile uint32_t*) (TIM15_BASE+0x24))
#define TIM15_PSC (*(volatile uint32_t*) (TIM15_BASE+0x28))
#define TIM15_ARR (*(volatile uint32_t*) (TIM15_BASE+0x2C))
```

Comment: Did you try to look into what exactly goes wrong? Did you check if the counter of TIM17 actually ticks? Did you check with a debugger (or at the very least debug print) how it behaves in ms_delay function? What the actual values of local variables are in there? The reference manual suggests timers 16 and 17 are fully identical, and all your register mappings seem correct, and you provide clock to the timers correctly as well. Need to check TIM17 registers at runtime. Maybe you need a couple dummy instructions after `RCC_APB2ENR |=1<<18;` (waste a couple cycles after it).

Comment: Hi @Ilya, I have check the code and I found that it stops before the while `while((TIM17_SR & TIM_SR_UIF)==0);` cycle, I found that in the case of TIM17 `TIM17_SR` is 0, while in the case TIM16 or TIM15 `TIM16_SR` and `TIM15_SR` are 1, then I found that TIM17 still disabled, for some reason `TIM17_CR1 |=1;` doesn't make the change in the register.

Comment: I think that maybe as JW says in the answer, the STM32L432KC doesn't have a TIM17.

Answer (score 1):

There is no TIM17 in STM32L432KC.

You may want to stick to using the [vendor-provided CMSIS-required device header](https://github.com/STMicroelectronics/cmsis_device_l4/blob/013bf0e41256ffbc2b539676f2007d08b297a86a/Include/stm32l432xx.h#L1), instead of "inventing" your own, which then leads to this kind of errors.

Comment: Thank you, I know this could help, but part of the homework is to make the same code work with TIM17, so I don't know If the change will be accepted, I found that TIM17 still disabled in my code, so I think something is wrong with the register. I think the same, that STM32L432KC doesn't have a TIM17 because I haven't founded it in the reference manual for it, but my teacher uses the reference manual for the STM32L4+ Series, so I think maybe only the L432KC from the L4+ series doesn't have it.

Comment: Your teacher has to accept facts: the 'L4+ RM does not cover the 'L432 and 'L432 is one of the lowest-range 'L4 which does not have TIM17.

Comment: L4+ would be named like: STM32L4P / STM32L4Q / STM32L4R / STM32L4S